# Backing-up to an untrusted cloud

Tags: encryption, ssh, backup, luks, cloud-storage

Not sure if this kind of review/validation question is allowed - please delete if it isn't.

[Like](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/229256) [many](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113218) [before](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123831), I'm looking for ways to do cloud backup in a way where I trust that I'm still the only one with access to the information.

Context / goals / hypothesis:

- data is natively stored on a Linux computer
- information loss isn't a concern - I have other backups, but the current "offsite" component doesn't satisfy me.

The core idea is well described in [this blog post](https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2017/09/05/encrypt-backups-untrusted-remote-location/). Summarizing, the strategy consists in:

- obtaining access to a remote server that provides ssh access
- mounting that server's filesystem over SSHFS
- creating a large file over there, and set it up as a LUKS/cryptsetup loop container
- mounting the file locally as loop
- and backing-up into the loop file

Questions:

- My understanding is that in this case, the encryption key is never seen by the remote server - so even if the SSH connection was to be listened to, the key wouldn't be compromized.
- This strategy assumes that SSHFS and LUKS/cryptsetup are "wise" enough to only transfer blocks which are required for I/O operations - not the whole file. Is this the case? Would a different "filesystem-over-network" be more appropriate ?
- Any other hole/weakness in this strategy?

Thanks